# Introduce to clients selective operation subset from alone wsdl

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws

At the moment we are developing JAX-WS (2.0) service, deploying to IBM WebSphere (7.0) and we have need to introduce to clients several instances of this service with various subsets of original service operations .
Is there any way to do this without creating several implementations of service and wsdls - just from one service and one wsdl?
Or maybe disable unallowed operations after deploy.
Thnx

Comment: Did you consider using an authorization scheme, where users have access to different sets of services?

Comment: It isn't preferable solution for us, maybe smth easier exist?

Comment: Could you please post some fragments so we can better understand your point?